# Google API 1.8.1 - GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync hangs under Windows service

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() for authorizing user for GoogleDrive.

It works OK with console or UI application, but hangs if the method is executed within the context of a Windows service, even if I was authorized before in a console mode and JSON data is stored in the provided FileDataStore.

My code is following:

```
ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets { ClientId = CLIENT_ID, ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET };

FileDataStore store = new FileDataStore("MyFolder");

UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    secrets,
                    new string[] {
                        DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                        DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    store).Result;
```

Is this method is not working under Windows Service at all, or I am missing something?

Is there is an alternative way authorize user under Windows service? (I am not interested in ServiceAccountCredential for this case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you call the async mode? (I mean using async-await, or even ContinueWith)

Comment: peleyal, does not 'AuthorizeAsync' method intended to be async?

Comment: peleyal, actually the sample code is actually invoked from within the Task.Start(), so it is running asynchronously. Do you have other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Found a reason: It was because the UI authorization has been performed from one user account, while the service was running under another user account.

Comment: Does it work in window service. I am facing same problem. Can anyone help to fix this problem

Comment: Shyam sundar shah, you have to run windows service with the same user account, which you used to do a manual web authorization.

Comment: Facing same issue in my application. Not able to authenticate user using windows service. I have tried above mentioned changes. But with no luck/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Open Services. Go to Properties on your service. Under Log On tab, check "Allow service to interact with desktop".

This is required for any service to do anything UI related.